# how do u add colour / texture

Tags: texturing, materials, color

hi I'm kinda new to blender and I've managed to create a object buy sculpting it ( a face ) but no matter which youtube videos I watch or web pages I read I just can't add colour / texture. Manny sites are saying about a dot next to my colour option but there is no dot next to it! and when I click anywhere on it I am just taken to a simple colour wheel (which even if that's what I wanted it don't change the colour of the object) . 
I've also seen things to do with the uv panel and tried that ( it didn't work) and also I've tried downloading a JPG image but still nothing happened. I hope one of u can help Xo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let's say this cube is the face you made

(step 3 is very important)

1
[image]

2
[image]

**3**
[image]

4[image]